# Editing string in a list inside a dictionary in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, lowercase

If I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'alfa': ['Computer Science'], 'beta': ['book', 'CompUter']}
```

And I want to turn it into a dictionary like this:

```
{'alfa': ['computer science'], 'beta': ['book', 'computer']}
```

So basically turn the words into lowercase letters.
for this i know I would need the function lower().

However, I do not know how to access the words inside the dictionary, so that I could use this function.

Before putting the list into the dictionary, I tried this:

```
for z in wordlist:
    z.lower()
```

But it didn't do anything to the words.

Comment: It's probably easier to just replace elements instead of thinking of "editing" them. (Strings _must_ be done this way.) Try looping over your dictionary and replacing the values with a list comprehension that lowercases everything in the list?

Comment: (This assumes your data structure is pretty uniformly like what you showed. You need to add to your requirements if you have "misbehaving" keys or values.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_dict = {'alfa': ['Computer Science'], 'beta': ['book', 'CompUter']}

for key in my_dict:
    my_dict[key] = [my_str.lower() for my_str in my_dict[key]]

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'alfa': ['computer science'], 'beta': ['book', 'computer']}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Works like a dream.